Сложить значения в каждом из 3 столбцов, если значения относятся к одному id
в таблице есть 4 столбца
в первом столбце есть повторяющиеся id
нужно посчитать сумму значений в столбцах 2-4, которые относятся одному и тому же айди из столбца 1


Там сводных таблиц разве нет?

libreOffice, Excel рядом с этой таблицей, вывести уникальные id и на против уникальных написать формулу =СУММЕСЛИ(A$2:A$21;A29;B$2:B$21) =СУММЕСЛИ(A$2:A$21;A29;C$2:C$21) =СУММЕСЛИ(A$2:A$21;A29;D$2:D$21)
Для Google таблиц =QUERY(A1:D20; "SELECT A, SUM(B), SUM(C), SUM(D) GROUP BY A")


Как вариант:
=SUM((FILTER(B:D;A:A=A1)))
=BYCOL(B1:D;LAMBDA(_col;SUM(FILTER(_col;A:A=A1))))
